# How do I factorise $729^x-243^x-81^x+9^x+3^x-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, factoring

> How do I factorise $$729^x-243^x-81^x+9^x+3^x-1 ?$$

I know the answer is $(3^x-1)(9^x-1)(27^x-1)$, but I have no idea how to go about it. This is actually a step of another question in my book. Would someone please help?

Comment: Have you noticed that all the bases are powers of $3$?

Comment: Notice, by the way, that $9^x - 1$ factors further as $(3^x + 1) (3^x - 1)$, and $27^x - 1$ factors further, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Write the expression in terms of $u := 3^x$. For example, $9^x = (3^2)^x = (3^x)^2 = u^2$.

Comment: I get $ u^4(u^2-u-1)+(u^2+u-1). $ What do I do to this to get the required answer?

Comment: Expanding, you can write this as $u^6 - u^5 - u^4 + u^2 + u - 1$, and we can start looking for factors. The Rational Root Theorem tells us that the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1$, so we can check both of these. If we find that one is a root, we can use polynomial long division to divide by $u - (\pm 1) = u \mp 1$, respectively. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 1):

From $y=3^x$ we get:

$$y^6-y^5-y^4+y^2+y-1=0$$
Can you see $y=1$ and $y=-1$ are solutions to this?

Hence we have:
$$y^6-y^5-y^4+y^2+y-1=(y^2-1)(ay^4+by^3+cy^2+dy+f)$$
Work out the quartic if then try to reduce it further.